# how to use scroll component in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I'm a bit confused with the scrollView component that "seems" to be supported in jquery.mobile.

[Here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html) I can see it says:

> To turn an element into a scrollview, simply add a
>   `data-scroll="true"` to the element. By default, a scrollview
>   can scroll in both the horizontal and vertical directions. If the user
>   drags the view horizontally (left or right), or vertically (up or
>   down), scrolling will be locked so that it only scrolls in that one
>   dimension. If the user drags the view diagonally, he will be able to
>   scroll in both directions at the same time.

I added the attribute mentioned in the above quote, but nothing happens! I tried to inspect HTML in the page (linked above) and I also added the following resources to my page. but nothing happens! I don't event get any error complaining about a missing component or something.

- jquery.easing.1.3.js
- jquery.mobile.scrollview.js
- jquery.mobile.scrollview.css

I would appreciate if anyone can help.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this js after `jquery.easing.1.3.js` and `jquery.mobile.scrollview.js` - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/experiments/scrollview/

Comment: Thank! I'm surprised that this is very badly documented!

Comment: Even I had faced the same issue.Glad to be of help.